# history.back() clears form values

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, history

I have a form where the user entered some information.
After clicking on the submit button, a script check the entries.
If there's something wrong, the user has to go back and fix it.

But when I use `history.back()`, the page will be reloaded and all entries are gone.
How can I make that work with jQuery Mobile?

```
<a href="javascript:history.back()" data-icon="back" data-role="button" data-theme="b">Back</a>
```

Comment: it there any ajax call going on??

Comment: Had you got any follow-ups on this?

Answer (score 0):

Simply try this

```
javascript:history.go(-1)
```

This is worth reading to...
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history

These are Plugins..If You don't want to add plugins then avoid it..but it works great and servers the purpose.

http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-bbq-plugin/

https://github.com/browserstate/history.js

In any case you will have to add some logic to make the data persist in some state or session to use it when you come back.

**Jquery Mobile Specific solution:**

```
data-rel="back" on anchor tag.
```

http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a4.1/#docs/forms/../../docs/content/../../docs/forms/../../docs/forms/../../docs/pages/docs-pages.html
See Back Linking in JQuery Mobile.